# Connect a system with Active Directory (AD)

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, mantis

I followed all the instructions to connect Mantis to AD, until I created a specific user in AD and even then I can not connect the two for AD authentication.

**error:**

> 'ldap_search(): Search: Bad search filter' in
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mantisbt-2.0.0\core\ldap_api.php' line 335

[**Original instructions from the developer site**](https://www.mantisbt.org/manual/admin.config.auth.html#ADMIN.CONFIG.AUTH.LDAP)

**My Settings:**

```
$g_login_method = LDAP;
$g_ldap_server = 'ldap://IP_Server:389';  
$g_ldap_root_dn = 'dc=company,dc=technology'; 
$g_ldap_organization = 'company technology';
$g_ldap_protocol_version = 3; 
$g_ldap_uid_field = 'sAMAccountName';
$g_ldap_realname_field = 'cn';
$g_use_ldap_realname = ON; 
$g_use_ldap_email = ON;
$g_ldap_bind_dn =  'mantis'; //User AD
$g_ldap_bind_passwd = '*******'; //Password AD
$g_ldap_follow_referrals = ON;
$g_log_level = LOG_LDAP;
$g_log_destination = 'file:C:\mantisbt.log';
```

**LOG**

```
> ldap_api.php:326 ldap_authenticate_by_username() Binding to LDAP
> server ldap_api.php:63 ldap_connect_bind() Attempting connection to
> LDAP server/URI 'ldap://IP_Server:389'. ldap_api.php:66
> ldap_connect_bind() Connection accepted by LDAP server ldap_api.php:79
> ldap_connect_bind() Setting LDAP protocol version to 3
> ldap_api.php:101 ldap_connect_bind() Attempting bind to ldap server
> with username and password ldap_api.php:114 ldap_connect_bind() Bind
> to ldap server successful ldap_api.php:334
> ldap_authenticate_by_username() Searching for (&company technology(sAMAccountName=paulo.roberto))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enter a valid search filter for $g_ldap_organization, if you want to restrict the entries available for authentication.  Most likely you want to leave this variable empty.

Comment: But the variable is filled with the name of the company, as it was passed to me by the support team.
$ G_ldap_organization = 'company technology';

Comment: They made a mistake, obviously.  Even the page you linked says so. If multiple organizations are using your LDAP server, a value like `(company=name of your company)` could be useful.

Comment: And how would that string look? Can you give me an example?

The fact that you have two separate Company Technology names may be causing some error in interpreting the space character? Or has nothing to do?

Comment: I can only guess: Take the value they gave you, prepend `o=` and put the whole string in parentheses like `(o=company technology)`.

Comment: It did not work, I tried some combinations, without success.

Comment: Now it's time to go back to the support team and ask them for a complete filter expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.